# Questions about iOS pan gesture

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have two questions I can't resolve about pan gesture.

I used the pan gesture to control the variable of num,

**the first question** is when I end pan gesture,

the variable still increase or decrease 1 or 2,

can't get the number what I want percisely

even I had override UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded

**the second question** is One of the functions is

to detect the direction of pan gesture.

When I drag up or down on the screen,

the num stay in 100~110 a bit and then continue to move,

which means the pan gesture will stop a bit when it moves.

the number stay like 100 ~ 110 then continue working,

Could anyone help me how to solve those problems,

Thanks in advance for any comment.

here is the code below:

```
- (IBAction)panToControlNum:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    //    CGPoint vel = [sender translationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint vel = [sender velocityInView:self.view];
    if (vel.x > 0)
    {   // user dragged towards the right
        vel.x = 0;
        num++;
    }
    else if(vel.x < 0)
    {   // user dragged towards the left
        vel.x = 0;
        num--;
    }
    else if(vel.y < 0)
    {   // user dragged towards the up
        vel.y = 0;
        num++;
    }
    else if(vel.y > 0)
    {   // user dragged towards the down
        vel.y = 0;
        num--;
    }

    switch (sender.state)
    {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            NSLog(@"pan gesture start ened , do nothing");
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
@end



2015-08-27 00:54:24.297 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag up, num is 160
2015-08-27 00:54:24.313 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag up, num is 161
2015-08-27 00:54:24.330 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag up, num is 162
2015-08-27 00:54:24.363 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag up, num is 163
2015-08-27 00:54:24.380 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag up, num is 164
2015-08-27 00:54:24.397 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag up, num is 165
2015-08-27 00:54:24.413 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag left, num is 164
2015-08-27 00:54:24.430 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag left, num is 163
2015-08-27 00:54:24.463 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag up, num is 164
2015-08-27 00:54:24.513 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag left, num is 163
2015-08-27 00:54:24.530 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag left, num is 162
2015-08-27 00:54:24.547 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag up, num is 163
2015-08-27 00:54:24.563 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag up, num is 164
2015-08-27 00:54:24.580 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag up, num is 165
2015-08-27 00:54:24.597 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag up, num is 166
2015-08-27 00:54:24.613 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag up, num is 167
2015-08-27 00:54:24.630 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag up, num is 168
2015-08-27 00:54:24.647 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag up, num is 169
2015-08-27 00:54:24.663 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag up, num is 170
2015-08-27 00:54:24.680 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag left, num is 169
2015-08-27 00:54:24.697 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag left, num is 168
2015-08-27 00:54:24.713 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag up, num is 169
2015-08-27 00:54:24.730 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag up, num is 170
2015-08-27 00:54:24.747 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag left, num is 169
2015-08-27 00:54:24.764 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag left, num is 168
2015-08-27 00:54:24.780 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag left, num is 167
2015-08-27 00:54:24.797 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag up, num is 168
2015-08-27 00:54:24.814 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag up, num is 169
2015-08-27 00:54:24.847 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag up, num is 170
2015-08-27 00:54:24.864 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag left, num is 169
2015-08-27 00:54:24.880 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag left, num is 168
2015-08-27 00:54:24.897 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag left, num is 167
2015-08-27 00:54:24.914 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag left, num is 166
2015-08-27 00:54:24.930 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag left, num is 165
2015-08-27 00:54:24.947 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag left, num is 164
2015-08-27 00:54:24.964 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag up, num is 165
2015-08-27 00:54:24.997 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag left, num is 164
2015-08-27 00:54:25.014 TickTok[2657:1264792] pan gesture drag left, num is 163
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly ?

Comment: to control the variable of num

Comment: you are being a bit unclear could you describe the expected behavior and the current behavior ?

Comment: i want to make a metronome, and control the tempo through pan gesture, but there are two bug in this gesture.

Comment: When I drag up or down on the screen, the num stay in 100~110 a bit and then continue to move, which means the pan gesture will stop a bit while it moves.

Comment: could you use NSLog() ; to log the value of num , and post the log here?

Comment: I updated the NSlog, i realise when i drag in the top left corner the num stopped increasing, how could I slove this problem .. thanks a lot

Comment: so when you drag to the upper left corner there is log ?